# New user signup causing error in admin view - ?missing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

A user has signed up for my website but when I try to view their details via the admin area I get a heroku error. I'm not sure what has happened here to cause this, or if there is a problem with our signup form leaving us open to allowing errors.

I've checked in my heroku console and the user's details are:

```
#<Bride id: 95, name: "Ted", address: nil, city: "London", postcode: nil, email: "tedlondon@gmail.com", age: nil, source: "Other", wedding_date: nil, username: "tedlondon", password_digest: "$2a$10$sKkcY2kMT.xkD2tVKSyMRe/J.W0jGZCJtYkuLaEsdYsV...", created_at: "2014-06-25 22:17:44", updated_at: "2014-06-25 22:17:44", avatar: "", wedding_place: "", last_login: nil, source_other: "twitter", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil>
```

In the heroku logs, the error is:

```
Processing by Admin::BridesController#show as HTML
app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"95"}
app[web.1]:   Rendered admin/brides/show.html.haml within layouts/admin_application (3.1ms)
app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/brides/95"  request_id=82bac3d0-a38a-4661-8e55-f17eb4c4f591 fwd="14.200.95.104" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=443ms status=500 bytes=1575
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
app[web.1]:     40:       %h5 Wedding
app[web.1]:     42:         Wedding is on:
app[web.1]:     43:         %strong= @bride.wedding_date.to_s(:long)
app[web.1]:     41:       %p
app[web.1]:     45:         Place of wedding is:
app[web.1]:     44:       %p
app[web.1]:     46:         %strong= @bride.wedding_place
app[web.1]:   app/views/admin/brides/show.html.haml:43:in `_app_views_admin_brides_show_html_haml__4141687763027929215_70052807875360'
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]:   app/views/admin/brides/show.html.haml:43:in `to_s'
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: ** [Airbrake] Failure: Net::HTTPUnauthorized
heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=gtb.herokuapp.com request_id=3526a39a-2cf1-4259-ae08-00c028f39993 fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=301 bytes=184
```

Is anyone able to help me work out how they have created a user account causing an error?

Comment: Does your code works on your local machine? and i think the error is in your `to_s` method. what is :long here?

Comment: the to_s method can get a number of parameters, have a look http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well is not working because you try to get the value from a column which is empty and after that do a to_s on a nil value.

If you want to allow nil, and perform a to_s, `try` it might help you.

```
@bride.wedding_date.to_s.try(:long)
```

Do the same with the rest of your columns, where you allow nil.

Comment: yes, that's it, thank you. I allow users to sign up without a wedding date but then the to_s causes a problem. much appreciated

Comment: Sorry I was just testing my answer, to have the same output and allow nil, check my new answer.